# how to close slidable by tapping on the screen in flutter

Tags: javascript, python, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Is there a way to close a slidable in flutter by tapping on the screen instead of sliding back? I just want the slidable to slide back automatically when there is any other interaction on the screen. Here is the section of my code where i added the slidable Widget.
Thank you in advance

```
Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(
                //children: List.generate(todos.length, (index) => null),
                itemCount: todos.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int i){
                    return Slidable(
                      dismissal: SlidableDismissal(
                        child: SlidableDrawerDismissal(),
                        onDismissed: (actionType) {
                          setState(() {
                            todos.removeAt(i);
                          });
                        },
                      ),
                      key: ValueKey(todos[i]),
                      actionPane: SlidableScrollActionPane(),
                      actionExtentRatio: 0.25,
                      child: ListTile(
                        onTap: (){
                          setState(() {
                            _isVisible= !_isVisible;
                          });
                        },
                        title: Row(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: <Widget>[

                            Container(
                              child: CustomCheckbox(
                                  selectedColor: Color(0xFF005ef5)
                              ),
                            ),

                            SizedBox(
                              width: 5, // here put the desired space between the icon and the text
                            ),
                            Flexible(
                                child: Text(
                                  todos[i],
                                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1,
                                )
                            ) // here we could use a column widget if we want to add a subtitle
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      actions: <Widget>[
                        IconSlideAction(
                          icon: Icons.close,
                          caption: 'Delete',
                          color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                          onTap: (){
                            setState(() {
                              todos.removeAt(i);
                            });
                          },
                        )
                      ],
                    );
                },
              ),
            ),
```

Comment: What do you mean with slidable? I'd like to know which widget you are referring to, so maybe I could help :)

Comment: i have a list view builder with list tiles in it, i wrapped the list tiles in a slidable Widget.

Comment: Ok. Next would would be if you could share your code with us, in order to have a more visible perspective 

Comment: I have edited the question and added the section of my code where the slidable is used, please let me know if you need anything else in other to help, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can set the `closeonTap:true` inside `IconSlideAction()`